# How to scroll focused TextBox with large text

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I've got a grid containing a header, a textbox and a footer. The header and the footer occupy as much space as needed, the remainder should be filled by the textbox entirely. This is what I've got so far:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <Grid  x:Name="TitlePanel"  Grid.Row="0">
    <TextBlock Text="Title" />
  </Grid>

  <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0">
    <ScrollViewer Margin="0">
      <TextBox x:Name="NoteText"
                InputScope="Text"
                AcceptsReturn="True"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                TextAlignment="Left"
                TextWrapping="Wrap"
                FontSize="24"
                BorderThickness="0">
      </TextBox>
    </ScrollViewer>
  </Grid>

  <Grid x:Name="Footer" Grid.Row="2">
    <TextBlock Text="Footer"/>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

This set up gives me the lay-out I want. The problem, however, is that when the Textbox contains large amounts of text scrolling does not work the way I want.

Suppose the textbox contains twice as much text than can be displayed. As long as the textbox doesn't have the focus, scrolling works just fine. When I set focus on the textbox and put the caret at the first position, I cannot scroll to the end of the textbox. When I put the caret at the last position, I cannot scroll to the top of the textbox.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple solution already built into the TextBoxcontrol, it's called [verticalscrollbarvisibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.verticalscrollbarvisibility.aspx).

It adds, as the name suggests, a vertical scrollbar to the TextBox.

This eliminates the need for the ScrollViewer that you have in your markup.

### Edit

I've made a very simple test to show that it works:

```
<TextBox Width="100"
         Height="100"
         VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
         TextWrapping="Wrap"
         Text="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789" />
```

If you copy & paste that control to a new project and run it, you'll see that the option works.

In your specific case, there must be another option conflicting to cause it not to work.

Comment: When I set `VerticalScrollBarVisibility=Visible` and remove the `ScrollViewer` the textbox won't scroll at all.

Comment: Try setting it to Auto.

Comment: I must be doing something seriously wrong here. Steps I took. File | New | Project... Windows Phone App. Added your example to the StackPanel named TitlePanel. When I run it, the content of the TextBox does not scroll...

Comment: No, this is a derp on my side. I thought this was WPF, I missed the Windows Phone tag... On the other side, according to [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/e828004a-6545-4e52-a6ba-6148b9e3c5b7/how-to-enable-scrolling-in-textbox-for-windows-phone-8-app?forum=wpdevelop), the max rendersize for controls is 2000-ish pixels, so text that is longer than that will no longer be rendered. Maybe that is the issue.

Comment: Though the property is still [valid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.controls.textbox.verticalscrollbarvisibility%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) for Windows Phone.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. I created a Style for textbox and that work for me, may this will also help you. No need to use ScrollViewer.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="PhoneDisabledTextBoxTemplate" TargetType="TextBox">
            <ContentControl x:Name="ContentElement" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxInnerMargin}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
        </ControlTemplate>

        <Style x:Key="AppVerticalTextBoxStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Cambria"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="26"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                        <Grid Background="Transparent" >
                            <Grid>
                                <ScrollViewer x:Name="EnabledBorder" BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="1" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
                                    <ContentControl x:Name="ContentElement" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="Top"  />
                                </ScrollViewer>
                                <Border x:Name="DisabledOrReadonlyBorder" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="#FF71B68D" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}" Visibility="Collapsed">
                                    <Border.BorderBrush>
                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledColor}"/>
                                    </Border.BorderBrush>
                                    <TextBox x:Name="DisabledOrReadonlyContent" Background="Transparent" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionForeground="{TemplateBinding SelectionForeground}" SelectionBackground="{TemplateBinding SelectionBackground}" TextAlignment="{TemplateBinding TextAlignment}" TextWrapping="{TemplateBinding TextWrapping}" Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" Template="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledTextBoxTemplate}"/>
                                </Border>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

//Remove ScrollViewer from your code.

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0">

      <TextBox x:Name="NoteText"
                InputScope="Text"
                AcceptsReturn="True"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                TextAlignment="Left"
                TextWrapping="Wrap"
                FontSize="24"
                BorderThickness="0"
                Style="{StaticResource AppVerticalTextBoxStyle}" TextWrapping="Wrap">
      </TextBox>   
  </Grid>
```

Comment: I'm sorry to say this answer is not a solution to my problem. I still cannot scroll properly. Besides that, the solution seems to have serious impact on performance and the selection markers get displaced as well.